Parallel token update
My problem:
I'm receiving an expiration token from someone else's API. My task is to request a new token only at the time I set (for example, once every 1 minute). My service receives hundreds of requests simultaneously. And when the time comes to refresh the token, my code requests a hundred new tokens.
When I do a test where I first request one token, and then make a request for several tokens in parallel, I am returned the one that has already been created. But if I immediately try to make a hundred simultaneous requests, then everyone will receive a new token.
How best to cope with the task? Here's how it works now.
_timeGetToken - time to receive token
tokenUpdateTime - time after which the token needs to be renewed(double, minutes(1))
public async Task<string> GetToken()
{
    if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(_timeGetToken) > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tokenUpdateTime))
    {
        try
        {
            token = await _api.GetToken(new TokenUser());
            _timeGetToken = DateTime.Now;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    if(token != null) 
        return token.Token;
    return string.Empty;
}

My Test:
var t1 = await tokenHandler.GetToken();

List<Task<string>> tokensTasks = new();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    tokensTasks.Add(tokenHandler.GetToken());

var tokens = await Task.WhenAll(tokensTasks);

If I do this then I will get the same token,
but if I remove the first token request, I will get a hundred different tokens
//var t1 = await tokenHandler.GetToken();

List<Task<string>> tokensTasks = new();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    tokensTasks.Add(tokenHandler.GetToken());

var tokens = await Task.WhenAll(tokensTasks);

At first I decided that it was worth using semaphore, but it became clear that in this code they will not help me in any way, I mean that I need to calculate the lifetime of the token in a different way or store it differently.
Thanks in advance for any advice

Related: Enforce an async method to be called lazily on demand, and called again when the previous result has expired.

To prevent multiple simultaneous token refreshes in a concurrent environment, you can use a SemaphoreSlim as an asynchronous lock. This ensures that only one thread can execute the token-refreshing code at a time. Here’s how to integrate SemaphoreSlim into your GetToken method along with a double-checked locking pattern:
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _tokenRefreshLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

public async Task<string> GetToken()
{
    // First check to see if the token needs refreshing
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_timeGetToken) > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tokenUpdateTime))
    {
        bool acquiredLock = false;
        try
        {
            // Acquire the lock
            await _tokenRefreshLock.WaitAsync();
            acquiredLock = true;

            // Double-check to see if another task has already refreshed the token
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_timeGetToken) > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tokenUpdateTime))
            {
                token = await _api.GetToken(new TokenUser());
                _timeGetToken = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure the lock is released
            if (acquiredLock)
            {
                _tokenRefreshLock.Release();
            }
        }
    }

    return token != null ? token.Token : string.Empty;
}

This approach significantly reduces the likelihood of multiple threads entering the token refresh logic simultaneously, as the first check may prevent most unnecessary lock acquisitions, and the second check, done after acquiring the lock, ensures that only one refresh happens even if multiple threads pass the first check.

It seems to me that this will significantly slow down the work if 1000 requests are waiting for example. Is not it so?

it shouldn't be severe, as far as I analyse and remember how the .net works. You have to choose if you want to make only one request to the other service or not. If you have to, then synchronisation is unavoidable and some performance penalty will come with it, but it shouldn't be a significant slowdown. In my opinion, this slowdown is negligible, as, without it, each task will have to make a call to external service which most likely will be a bigger hit on performance.

yes, you're right, my tests didn't show any performance degradation, I'll use your example, thanks

What's the purpose of the bool acquiredLock variable? It seems redundant to me.

The double-checked locking pattern is dangerous, and your implementation of it is flawed. Don't use it, unless you are an expert in lock-free multithreading, and you have precise knowledge of the hardware/OS configuration that your program will run. Just put all access of the shared state inside the lock, and you won't have to worry about reordering of instructions or torn values.
